# Hide timer and display text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to display the text box in place of the timer, as soon as the timer comes to **0**. And the timer should hide after displaying the box. 
I'm looking for a simple logic either with 'v-show' or 'destroy' property in vue.js.

```
mounted () {
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (this.value === 0) {
    return (this.value = 3)
  }
  this.value += -1
}, 1000)
}
```

Code at link
 https://codepen.io/prasanna_sri/pen/rdravJ

Comment: It loops because of `return (this.value = 3)`. Add your display/hide code inside the if.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-if` and the `v-else` directives to toggle between the two elements.

I've updated your codepen and done the following:

- Added a default value (3) to your data value.
- changed `return (this.value = 3)` to `return`, so the callback doesn't run indefinitely.
- Added `v-if="this.value"` on your progress component
- Added `v-else` on your text box

Please note that if you would like to toggle the progress bar often, you should use the `v-show` directive instead. `v-if` has higher toggle cost, while `v-show` has a higher render cost because it's always rendered in the dom but hidden with the CSS `display:none` property.